# Cannot move window

Tags: macos, vmware

I install a linux (Fedora) distribution through VMWare (4.0) on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. The the virtual machine open up at the top of the window and hide its taskbar underneath the apple task bar as shown in below image:

[image]

Now I cannot move the virtual machine window. Solution?

Answer (score 1):

I use two workarounds in cases like this.

1. In the *VMWare Fusion* **View** menu, select "Full Screen". The guest OS fills the entire Mac screen, except for a *Fusion* menu bar with menus **View**, **Virtual Machine**, and **Window**. Then from the **View** menu, select "Single Window". When the guest OS window comes back, it's shaped better to fit the host OS display.
2. Log in to the guest OS, then use the guest OS's control panel for display settings to reduce the size of the guest OS's display -- say to 1024x768. Then from the *Fusion* **View** menu, select "Single Window", if not already selected. The result is a guest OS window which takes up less of the host OS display. Adjust from there.